# Performance problems on SQL Server 2016 that goes away after running two updates flipping a null column value

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, sql-server-2016

This is an abstract question, at least to begin with. But I am looking for theories on why I am experiencing what I am experiencing.

I have a table with a number of columns, one of which is a Int that allows null. Lets refer to that as `NullableIntCol`.

We have a few non-clustered indexes on the table, some which includes the column here.

We are then Querying the table in various ways, some where we do a `WHERE NullableIntCol is null` and when we do that we are experiencing that the queries may take 5-10 seconds to execute. Fair, we need to optimize something.

In our test environment we have been able to replicate the issue. Although here we are talking 1-3 seconds. But the exact same pattern.

Datawise here the table has about 600.000 rows, ~350MB worth of data.

After we have played around with various combination of indexes etc. what I discovered was that if I run the following on the table:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable]
   SET [NullableIntCol] = -1
 WHERE [NullableIntCol] is null;
UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable]
   SET [NullableIntCol] = null
   WHERE [NullableIntCol] = -1;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Suddenly query performance is way way better. (50ms-200ms in our test env)

**This is the Query plan prior to executing the above.**

[image]
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1VCvT9uh

Estimated:

[image]
[image]

Executed:

[image]
[image]

---

**And this is the changed query plan after.**

[image]
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJXMu69_2

Estimated:

[image]

Executed:

[image]

Which is clearly a change. But I still lack the "Why".

Further.

I can then restore the database to the state it was before and again replicate the issue.

Initially I was thinking that it could perhaps be that the above almost triggered a full rebuild of the indexes, however rebuilding the indexes does not seem to have much effect if any at all.

So right now, I am out of theories on why I may see such a behavior.

**Update 2023-06-29**

---

After running `UPDATE STATISTICS [Scehma1].[Object1];` post the query above, it seems to go back to the bad query plan. Executing the `UPDATE FLIP -1 <==> null` where I see the performance improvement, it seems to namely update some statistics for that specific column, after running `UPDATE STATISTICS` it updates all of the statistics which seems to bring us back to the original Query plan.

I have been able to reproduce the two query plans by messing around with the Index1. And found the following.

The plan prior to any change: ~2 sec in dev env.
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJoclpcun
Index1 = Index1 bellow
Index2 = PK Index

If I disable the index used above (Index1 bellow) I get the following plan:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkrTzp5d2
Index1 = Index2 bellow
Index2 = PK Index

Finally if I change the index used initially (Index1 bellow) to:
`CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Index1] ON [Schema1].[Object1] ( [Column4] ASC, [Column9] ASC )` So switching the order of the columns. I then get:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r16QNpcd3

Now that I am actually making changes to the index, it makes quite allot more sense that I get changed plans, the question remains though, why it seems to pick such an sub-optimal plan in the beginning rather than just doing a table scan which is clearly faster. I Would get that when I begin to add paging and ordering on top it would

---

Now it's rather clear that these indexes has become a mess over time I think, we identified that rather quickly I think, but the strange thing to me was that the execution of that update statement changed so much. Which is perhaps answered now

**Table Schemas**

---

Tried to align it to the output from Sentry Plan Explorer, but it's probably not 100%. And it's not alligned to the old plans as I did not see the need to Anonomize all but Sentry Plan just takes it all.

```
CREATE TABLE [Schema1].[Object1](
    [Column1] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Column2] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [Column3] [varchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [Column4] [int] NULL,
    [Column5] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [Column6] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [Column7] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Column8] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [Column9] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Column10] [varchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [Column11] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [Column12] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Column13] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Column14] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Column15] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Object1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [Column1] ASC ) 
 WITH (
   PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
   STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
   IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
   ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
   ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, 
   OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF
   ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY];

ALTER TABLE [Schema1].[Object1] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Column14]
ALTER TABLE [Schema1].[Object1] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Column15]

ALTER TABLE [Schema1].[Object1]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Column9]
  FOREIGN KEY([Column9])
  REFERENCES [Schema1].[Object2] ([Column1])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE

ALTER TABLE [Schema1].[Object1] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Column9]

--
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Index0] ON [Schema1].[Object1] ( [Submitted] ASC )
  WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]

-- This Index is the one that goes in and out of our plans, whenever it's used it seems performance is tanked.
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Index1] ON [Schema1].[Object1] ( [Column9] ASC, [Column4] ASC )
  WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]

-- This has clearly not been updated as it should since all selects always includes all columns, so I guess that if it should make any sense to include what is currently there, 13,14 and 15 should be added as well
-- Not sure it has anything to do with the current problem though.
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Index2] ON [Schema1].[Object1] ( [Column9] ASC )
  INCLUDE([Column1],[Column2],[Column3],[Column4],[Column5],[Column6],[Column7],[Column8],[Column10],[Column11],[Column12]) 
  WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Index3] ON [Schema1].[Object1] ( [Column8] ASC )
  WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: You need to provide the actual execution plans for both slow and fast runs. Maybe it is tripping the column modification threshold for stats to be updated or you are just benefiting from the above bringing all the data into buffer cache. But a rebuild of indexes would also do those. Your query doesn't necessarily reverse back to the initial state though. Does the starting position definitely have no rows where NullableIntCol is already `-1`?

Comment: Though actually unless NullableIntCol is the leading column in the index then rebuilding the index won't update the stats there. So potentially an explanation. What are the estimated and actual rows for `WHERE NullableIntCol is null` in the bad plan and the good plan?

Comment: Should I include more than just the "picture" of the estimated query plan for now? It clearly changes after the update, but still searching for why so we can implement an improvement that remains - Running the query changes the same amount of rows in both passes, so there is no -1 values present already. It's approximately around 90% of all the rows that contain the value "NULL"

Comment: And NullableIntCol is not the leading column in any of the indexes. Instead it's in an index with a foreign key and those two are always queried together, so it will always be "WHERE MyFk = {id} AND NullableIntCol is null" and sometimes more filteres are added as well.

Comment: The XML for the plan would be better but likely in this case if you mouse over the arrows and look at what the estimated and actual rows are and let us know what they say (coming out of the index scan in the second plan and out of the index seek in the first one)  it will be enough as you are clearly trying to not post the object details

Comment: Are the rows where NullableIntCol is null correlated so that they are likely to be at the end of the range being seeked in the first index seek plan rather than evenly distributed throughout? So it is doing many more seeks and lookups before it finds 1,000 matching that (rather than the 1111 that would be expected if 90% match)

Comment: @MartinSmith Y, I realized after I had made the update, this is a bit back and forth at this point.

Comment: In the first plan it estimates that there will only be 20.58 rows coming out of the index seek so it will only need to do 20.58 key lookups. It is wrong by a factor of 50 as it needs to do1,000. In the second plan it scans 2328 rows before finding the first 1,000 matching the predicate as required by the TOP and can stop. This still seems catastrophically slow if it is taking 5-10 seconds to do 1,000 lookups though. What wait types does the slow query plan experience? I/O? Locks?

Comment: As for the distribution of NullableIntCol, they are probably likely to be distributed towards one end of the dataset, so if we order by creation time desc, paging (which happens also) it would be towards the end and reverse. The reason for focusing on this particular column is that it seems to affect all queries in varying degree that includes the "WHERE MyFk = {id} AND NullableIntCol is null" pattern. Order or no order. However that data is from our Telemetry so I have not dived deep into the patterns yet.

Comment: Please share the execution plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. If you want you can sanitize it using SentryOne Plan Explorer. Please also show the table and index definitions (again you can sanitize the names if you want). At a guess, removing the key lookup (by rearranging the index) would probably remove the chance of an index scan being picked. But hard to say without the right info.

Comment: @MartinSmith As for the 5-10 seconds, that is also from our telemetry, so it may be inflated a little bit as this is measured on the outside of the connection to the database - but it sit closely around the execution of the query. I can only execute the Queries directly in our test where we are typically talking 1-3 seconds, and that is where the plans above originates. I am more focused on the big change - both to the speed of the query and the patterns we see in our telemetry after.

Comment: @Charlieface Ill look into sanitizing and providing that, it will take a bit of time and I am off works soon so it may take a bit longer.

Comment: @Jens "*it will take a bit of time*" - Just to reiterate, SentryOne Plan Explorer will automatically sanitize it for you with one click of a button. Should make things rather simple.

Comment: @J.D. It wasn't that I didn't assume that, it was more that it was not a tool I know and getting it into our toolchain isn't quite as simple as just hitting download.

Comment: @Jens No worries, just making sure it was clear it's an easy process. You theoretically could just run it on your own machine and open the query plan from there to anonymize it too, if that's easier for ya.

Comment: I have added the query plans and also tried adding the schema so it's aligned as best as I could the the plans uploaded at https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ , cheers for that link @Charlieface ... But I think that statistics are the reasoning behind what we see, as stated by Andrea B. in the answer below.

Comment: @Jen the query plans you pasted are not the same you first posted in your questions. Your original plans had a TOP 1000 limit, which has an effect on how the query planner will try to optimize the queries.

Comment: @AndreaB. That was an oversigt, so I have to redo them :D - Again, trying to issolate things a bit here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the two plans is that in the first (slow) one, Sql Server expects that only 20 rows will satisfy the WHERE clause, and it resolves to use an index seek followed by lookups in the main table.
As it turns out, at least 1000 rows satisfy the clause and this plan comes out to be very inefficient because of the 1000 lookups.

In the second plan, Sql Server correctly estimates that at least 1000 rows will have to be retrieved, so it decides to do a full table scan (and it finds 1000 qualifying rows after reading just 2328 rows from the table).

Sql Server has a feature that auto updates the statistics of a table when a high percentage of the rows are modified.
Since, as you say, *It's approximately around 90% of all the rows that contain the value "NULL"*, the update of all those rows has triggered the auto update of the statistics of that table, allowing Sql server to choose a better plan.

You can test this by issuing an UPDATE STATISTICS command instead of your UPDATE block:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS [dbo].[MyTable];
```

EDIT:
It's also possible that in the first query there was no statistics available, and Sql server created them after your updates.
If the AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS option in on, the Query Optimizer creates statistics on individual columns used in a predicate, if these statistics are not already available. So the updates could have triggered the creation of statistics on [NullableIntCol] and the following query will find and use them.

In this case, you could obtain the same result with:

```
CREATE STATISTICS statistics_name
ON [dbo].[MyTable] (NullableIntCol)
WITH FULLSCAN;
```

**Update after your posting of the execution plans.**

Please note that the original queries you posted had a `TOP 1000` limit, which is absent in the query plans.
A limit on the total number of rows to be retrieved has an *high* impact on the query plan the optimizer will choose so you are comparing apples to oranges.

Also a `TOP 1000` has a meaning only if you specify an `ORDER BY`, which also have a big impact on the optimizer.

Nevertheless, the plans clearly show that 251959 rows satisfy your WHERE condition, out of a total of 569158. That's 44% of total rows.
No index lookup can be of any benefit if you have to retrieve such a large part of the table, so the best plan is always a table scan.
You could benefit from a covering index (which included all the columns you are selecting) but in your example you are selecting all columns of the table and such index would be a duplication of the whole table.

In such scenario, SQL server should never pick an index seek, *unless* it wrongly estimates that the percentage of rows satisfying the WHERE condition is much smaller. Having appropriate and updated statistics on `Column4` and `Column9` should avoid this.

But, if you are applying an `ORDER BY` and a `TOP 1000` limit, then an index on `Column4`, `Column9` and any further column specified in the `ORDER BY` could speed up the things by allowing to read just the first 1000 rows and then stop. This could be even faster if the index inlcuded all the columns needed in the select.

Also note that if you need even a single column not included in the index, sql server will have to do a lookup on the table for every row. So including 12 columns is useless if you select 15 columns and it just makes the index bigger and slower. Either include all the needed ones or don't include anything.

Comment: I really hoped you nailed it, it sounded so plausible that I had to log in from home to test it, unfortunately it did not quite go that way. Instead now it always stich to the "bad" plan. - However I think we have found out that the index it goes to is not good for the queries, I will post more details and plans tomorrow because an explanation would be nice.

Comment: Actually, there may be more to it, perhaps you are correct, it's just that the Query I execute seems to only update some of the statistics, I did not check all of them, but the first one that was changed was one for the NullableIntCol, but if I execute the UPDATE STATISTICS it updates all of the objects and then things goes back to the original plan. Could that make sense?

Comment: @Jens I added some more considerations after your updates.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's mostly caused by the fact that *both* plans are essentially bad plans. One does a full scan, the other does many lookups. You are asking the server to choose between a rock and a hard place.

Change one of your indexes to support the query properly

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Index2] ON [Schema1].[Object1]
    ( Column9, Column4 )
INCLUDE ([Column1],[Column2],[Column3],[Column5],[Column6],[Column7],[Column8],[Column10],[Column11],[Column12])
WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON);
```

The two key columns can be in either order.

Changing your clustered index to be on these two columns might make sense, depending on what other queries you have. The primary key does not need to be the clustering key.

`Index1` looks mostly useless, unless you are only querying on those two columns or you are doing a range lookup on whichever column is first in `Index2`, as `Index2` now covers the same key columns. I suggest you drop it.

Comment: There is no doubt that the Indexes is a mess, it's also clear that updating the ones we specifically defined was forgotten as the table was changed with more resent features. And so the plan is to basically kill all indexes and build new ones. Having focus on and Column9, Column4 makes sense as they will be part of almost all queries - the only exception is export of data where Column4 is left out of the filter.

Comment: When filtering on these two, another thing that is characteristic is that Column4 will ALWAYS be filtered against "is null", this it back to the export case where we are only ever interested in getting rows where this is not null for export, a feature rarely used. Column9 which is a FK will always be filtered for a single value, never a range, so it will always be = 1, = 2 = 42 etc...

Comment: Some of the rest of the columns are also part of the filtering process, but here this is more user driven, e.g. if they wish to filter for time ranges, or text values. So they are not always included.

Comment: Then perhaps you need a filtered index `WHERE (Column4 IS NULL)`

Comment: That could be, I am also considering pulling that data out of the table, simply having a secondary table that stores that data to simplify things from a Query perspective, this does mean we have to move data instead of just updating that column for a row. But the nature of such an update is that it goes from null to a value only once in it´s lifetime, and then it never changes again.

Comment: No don't do that, just make a view (and index it if you really need to) otherwise you will constantly have to keep this new table in sync

Comment: I have done similar concepts in the past and there has never been anything to keep in sync. So that is actually not a concern for me, this table does not receive many updates, the ones it does receive is mainly data scrubbing - but that would just have to be expanded to run on both tables which is not a huge deal IMO.